# Kafka Error: Could not find or load main class config.zookeeper.properties

Tags: apache-kafka

Searched everywhere, could not find a solution to my problem.

When I go to the directory after unpacking the binary version of Kafka (unpack it via terminal using the command tar -xzf), I try to start Zookeeper with the command (macOS Sierra):

*bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties*

I get the same error:

**Error: Could not find or load main class config.zookeeper.properties**

Download the latest binary version of Kafka (also tried earlier versions) - *kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.tgz* - the result is the same - the same error.

In posts here write that the error in the downloaded version - source instead of binary. I only have binary.

Java version with the latest update (build 1.8.0_141-b15).

What could be the problem?

Comment: where are you getting this version? The latest I see at the Apache download site is kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.tgz ( at http://www-us.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.11.0.0/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.tgz) and if I `tar -xvf kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0.tgz`, then `cd kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0`, and then run `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties` it starts fine on macOS Sierra

Comment: I've been sealed, you're right, the latest version is kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0
But the error has remained: (

Comment: The error is a CLASSPATH error so something in your environment is changing the Java classpath or you are not using Java 1.8. What does `java -version` report?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_131"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Comment: What's your PATH and CLASSPATH env variables and what directory are you in when you run bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh ?

Comment: Kafka is unpacked in the Downloads directory. I'm trying to start the Zookeeper first, and after Kafka. But when I start Zookeeper I catch this error and I can not move any further. 
PATH - /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java 
CLASSPATH - Its own folder, not the one that by default (set it in Eclipse)

Comment: unset CLASSPATH and try again. This works, it's your environment I'm quite sure.

Comment: Where in my case connection with the launch of Zookeeper and CLASSPATH? Classpath is important when building a JAR, what role does it play?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Comment: In Eclipse, I changed the classpath to default (default is Document /workspace). Nothing has changed, the error has remained. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Even in the terminal, I executed the command unset CLASSPATH

Comment: Do you have another machine to try or a virtual Linux machine to try to see it work

Comment: No Unfortunately (

Comment: What about running docker on the mac?

Comment: We will have to use it, since it does not work locally. In any case, thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe try the Confluent Open Source distribution of Kafka as it has some different start scripts. Confluent 3.3 is the release that includes Kafka 0.11. https://www.confluent.io/download/

Comment: Confluent showed an error "Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain" when try to start Kafka. I tried even to reinstall JDK - did not help.

Comment: I also tried to manually write CLASSPATH (again returned to the catalog kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0) "export CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}:.libs/zookeeper-3.4.10:.libs/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0" and run the Zookeeper - received an error "Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on my mac. It turned out the space of the path causing the problem. By removing it, it works.
/Users/xxx/My Projects/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0 => /Users/xxx/MyProjects/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0

Comment: There is no such folder in my user folder "MyProjects"

Comment: it is just an example. Does your path of kafka contains any spaces? If so, just remove it and see.

Comment: Kafka is not installed on the system. I have a downloaded distribution with all its files, and I'm trying to run it through the console. I wrote above all my actions above - but I catch a mistake.

Comment: What is the full path that you extracted the Kafka distribution and ran through the console?

Comment: User/Downloads/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Please run following commands:

```
wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.11.0.1/kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1.tgz
tar -xzf kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1.tgz
cd kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use complete path like this:
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh  /usr/local/Cellar/kafka/1.1.0/libexec/config/zookeeper.properties